# Remove anchor links / form targets within iframe content

Tags: php

Basically I have an IFRAME that contains a given page - I want to be able to remove all anchor links and form targets so that the user is not able to navigate to other pages within the IFRAME. Is this possible to do?

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
```

EDIT: RobinUS2 has provided a solution below, however how do I now remove all JavaScript events on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using PHP for doing this you should fetch the page and process it. Use a function like "file_get_contents()" and a regex to modify the HTML output.

However you might also consider using something like jQuery to dynamically manipulate the iframe.

In jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('#my-iframe').contents().find('a').click(function() { return false; });
$('#my-iframe').contents().find('form').submit(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: That's true, however if the iframe page itself also requires javascript it's a simple solution.

If your main goal is to prevent the "escape" of your visitors, over showing the iframe, you could also create the iframe with javscript.

Comment: Can you send me a link to your test site? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: OK it's working now: I have to enclose your code in: `$('#my-iframe').load(function(){`. Now do you know of any way to cancel any jQuery events on the page? e.g change() functions?

Comment: You might try:

    $('#my-iframe').contents().find('*').unbind();

Comment: That does not work I'm afraid. The events haven't been attached with bind().

Comment: "unbind()" can destroy all kinds of events, like the ones attached with "click()", "change()" et cetera.

Comment: OK. I think the problem may be that the element has `onchange="this.form.submit();` -  how can we cancel this?

Comment: Try $('#my-iframe').contents().find('form').removeAttr('onchange');

If this not works, try "*" instead of "form"

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. However what I don't understand is why doesn't `$('#my-iframe').contents().find('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
   });` handle this already?

Comment: Also I have noticed `$('#my-iframe').contents().find('*').unbind();` is stopping `$('#my-iframe').contents().find('a').click(function(){
    return false;
   });` from working.

Comment: Order does matter in this case: first apply the unbind all (*) and then the rest!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. You will have to use the string functions in PHP and maybe also buffering so you can work with the whole page once, and not to use chunks from it.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php