# Removing links in an iframe

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve exactly what you've done in this thread: [Remove anchor links / form targets within iframe content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176704/remove-anchor-links-form-targets-within-iframe-content)

I've tried wrapping the jQuery in a function like this:

```
$('#ifr').load(function(){
    $('#ifr').contents().find('a').click(function() { return false; });
}
```

But that isn't working. Do you have any tips or suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Did you wrap this code in an event handler, or within the `document.ready` event?

Comment: I hope your parent page and iframe page are in exactly same domain, otherwise your JS may not work because of Cross Site Scripting

Comment: I'm using <iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"> and it's a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#ifr').children('a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: `.children()` only goes one level down the DOM so I doubt that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind the event when the `iframe` has loaded. And use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior.

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j52ts/1/)

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
    // note the use o .each, you need to bind all elements
    $(this).contents().find("a").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); alert("click blocked")});
    });
});
```

The `iframe` must be from the same origin.